# how to access all models in one application to another application in same django project

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

the following is my installed appd in settings.py. I have imported all models of `administrator` to `management` in `models.py-managemant` using the code `from administrator.models import *` . Now I need to import models of `management` to `administrator`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'administrator.apps.AdministratorConfig',
    'vendoruser.apps.VendoruserConfig',
    'management.apps.ManagementConfig',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

when I used the code `from management.models import *` it shows the following errors

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f333c90ce18>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jeslin/project/ProEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jeslin/project/ProEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 112, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/jeslin/project/ProEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/jeslin/project/ProEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/jeslin/project/ProEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jeslin/project/ProEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/jeslin/project/ProEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/jeslin/project/ProEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/jeslin/project/ProEnv/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/jeslin/project/netfacer/administrator/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    from management.models import *
  File "/home/jeslin/project/netfacer/management/models.py", line 10, in <module>
    class vendor_users(models.Model):
  File "/home/jeslin/project/netfacer/management/models.py", line 12, in vendor_users
    vendor_id = models.ForeignKey(vendor_table, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
NameError: name 'vendor_table' is not defined
```

Comment: Well the error complains that in your `administrator.models`, you refer to a `vender_table` model, that is not yet defined. So it is an error in the file you want to import, not the import statement itself.